# Apply jQuery Function to Same Class of <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I have a listview control in ASPX page. I'm binding data to the listview from the database and I applied `.fadein()` and `.fadeout()` using jQuery script to the listview. I'm adding the same listview control with same class again to the same web page. Hence, the script works well only for one feature and not for the other one. The second feature control content has `display:none`.

How can I apply the same jQuery script for the feature which has same class name?

ASP code:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Flow" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" OnItemCommand="ListView1_OnItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="ListView1_ItemDataBound">     
  <LayoutTemplate>
       <div class="ticker twoRows medium">
            <ul class="latestNews">
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder" />
            </ul>
        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>               
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NewsTitle") %>'></asp:LinkButton>         
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDesc" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NewsDescription") %>'></asp:LinkButton>               
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

jQuery script:

```
var initializerRegion =function () {
    startTicker('.latestNews', 1, 3000);    
};

$(function () {     
    initializerRegion();
});
```

Comment: It is rather difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve. Would you mind to publish generated HTML code for both controls. Very useful would be to put it into http://jsfiddle.net/ and include your script as well.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds that livequery can fix your problem. Just take a look at the docs:

[livequery.js](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery)

Hope this will work for you.